# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/vol/web/static'

Tags: django, docker-compose, dockerfile

So I deployed my Django Project on local server, using docker, but I got this error:

**PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/vol/web/static'**

Here is my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/static/'
MEDIA_URL='/static/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'vol/web/media'
STATIC_ROOT = 'vol/web/static'
```

my settings.py is located in app/app/settings.py

urls.py:

```
from drf_spectacular.views import(
    SpectacularAPIView,
    SpectacularSwaggerView,
)
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include #include helps in importing urls from different apps
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/schema/',SpectacularAPIView.as_view(),name = 'api-schema'), #to generate schema
    path('api/docs/',
    SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='api-schema' ),  #to generate documentation using the schema provided above
    name = 'api-docs'), #using swagger to convert schema into document
    path('api/user/',include('user.urls')),
    path('api/recipe/', include('recipe.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL,
        document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    )
```

Comment: paste your url  main urls py

Comment: I have pasted the urls.py

Comment: If you are on linux give chmod 777 permissions to the static folder and subfiles.

Comment: If you have this error when using docker - show your dockerfile then. If docker-compose used - docker-compose config as well.